# Partition sort programming problem

Tags: c++, sorting

I need an algorithm to select the *k*th largest or smallest value. The values will be ints. My instructor told me to use a modified partition algorithm to find the *k*th largest or smallest value. Any thoughts?

Comment: Google for "partition sort algorithm"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is a description of the quickselect algorithm. I will assume that you want to find the *k*th smallest value.

1. Take the first element of your array. This will be your pivot. Keep track of its position.
2. Partition the array based on this pivot. Elements smaller than your pivot go before your pivot in the array; larger, after your pivot. (This step will move your pivot. Keep track of its position in your array.)
3. You now know that your pivot is larger than `pivot_position` number of elements. Therefore, your pivot is the (`pivot_position + 1`)th smallest element.

   - If *k* is equal to `pivot_position + 1`, then you've found your *k*th smallest value. Congratulations, return `pivot_position` as the position of that value in the array.
   - If *k* is less than `pivot_position + 1`, you want some value that's smaller than your pivot. Look in the part of the array before your pivot for the *k*th smallest value.
   - If *k* is greater than `pivot_position + 1`, you want some value that's larger than your pivot. Look in the part of the array after your pivot for the *k - (`pivot_position` + 1)*th smallest value (since that part of the array excludes the (`pivot_position` + 1) smallest values).

Since you're using C++, you should probably implement your functions as follows:

```
int select(int *array, int left, int right, int k);
int partition(int *array, int left, int right, int pivot_position);
```

`select` takes your array, left and right bounds, and your *k*. To clarify, `array[left]` will be the first element; `array[right]` will be the last; `right - left + 1` will be the length of the array. `select` returns the position of the *k*th smallest element.

`partition` takes your array, left and right bounds, and the starting position of your pivot. It's safe to just pass 0 for `pivot_position` every time, meaning that you want to use the first element in the array as the pivot. (In a variation called randomized quickselect, you pick a random `pivot_position`.) `partition` returns the position of the pivot after you're done moving things around.

Answer (score 1):

The STL has a `partial_sort` function that will sort the first k items of a sequence, and allowing you to grab that item with a simple lookup.

In other words, look for `std::partial_sort` and the rest will be obvious.

There is also a `nth_element` function in the STL.  I'm sure you can figure out how to use it.